# Configure error installing Ruby 1.9.3-p374

Tags: ruby, osx-mountain-lion

I would be grateful for any help I can get with installing `Ruby 1.9.3-p374` on `Mountain Lion OS X`.

I'm new to ruby and currently trying to upgrade from 1.8.7 but whenever I enter `rvm install 1.9.3-p374` in the command line I get:

```
user-macbook-pro-2:~ user$ rvm install 1.9.3-p374
No binary rubies available for: downloads/ruby-1.9.3-p374.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p374 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p374, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p374 - #extracted to /Users/user/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p374 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p374 - #configuring
Error running './configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374 --with-opt-dir=/Users/user/.rvm/usr', please read /Users/user/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p374/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.

ruby-1.9.3-p374 is not installed.
To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p374'
```

Any help on how to resolve this would be hugely appreciated. The error part is duplicated below:

```
  Error running './configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374 --with-opt-dir=/Users/user/.rvm/usr', please read /Users/user/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p374/configure.log
    There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.

    ruby-1.9.3-p374 is not installed.
```

The configure.log reads

```
[2013-01-23 08:00:31] ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374 --with-opt-dir=/Users/user/.rvm/usr
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Comment: what is in configure.log?

Comment: You should install Xcode

Comment: `To install do: 'rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p374'` Have you tried this?

Comment: Have you run 'rvm requirements'? That will give you a list of packages you'll need before you can install. Newer versions of Xcode can be tricky with rvm. Check http://rvm.io for info on that.

Comment: I already had xcode installed before trying to update, but installing "Command Line Tools (OS X Mountain Lion) for Xcode - November 2012', 21423)" seems to have sorted it - thanks everyone for your suggestions

Comment: you should put your solution as an answer to  yourself rather than hiding it in the comments (you should be able to answer your own question)

Answer (score 0):

I already had xcode installed before trying to update, but installing "Command Line Tools (OS X Mountain Lion) for Xcode - November 2012', 21423)" seems to have sorted it - thanks everyone for your suggestions